# .NET 6 startup class - Dynamically update extension methods parameters without restart

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, azure-app-configuration, app-startup

Lets say I have a startup.cs class with the following extension method (.AddXYZ) from an internal team.

```
builder.Services.AddXYZ(builder.Configuration, o =>
{
    o.Policy.Add(new InboundPolicyOptions()
    {
        ValidApplicationIds = builder.Configuration["AllowedAppIds"].Split(',').ToList(),
    });
 });
```

How can I update the above `ValidApplicationIds` list without having to restart the server.

I have tried using Azure App Configuration to store the list of ClientIds and tried testing dynamic refresh, but it did not help.

Please suggest.

Comment: Without understanding what  `AddXYZ` actually does - there is no way to tell. If you have control over the library you can rework the `InboundPolicyOptions` to use `IOptionsMonitor` for example (from the [options pattern for configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0#ioptionsmonitor)) instead of just accepting value read from the config. Or implement something similar.

Comment: Can you please share your Configuration file.